# Topology of indefinite orthogonal group O(p, q)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Wikipedia says in the Section on Topology of indefinite orthogonal group $O(p, q)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group#Topology

[image]

Can some folks clarify the statement, perhaps there is some mistake?

> In particular, it says that "The special orthogonal group has components $$\pi_0(SO(p, q)) = {(1, 1), (−1, −1)}$$ which either preserves both orientations or reverses both orientations, in either case preserving the overall orientation.
>
> I find $(−1, −1)$  may not be the $\mathbb Z_2$-generator switching between the disconnected sectors, unless $p+q$ satisfy certain constrain.
>
> Is Wikipedia wrong or imprecise?

Comment: What do you mean by "the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-generator switching between the disconnected sectors"? The notation is intended to describe a subgroup of $\pi_0(O(p, q)) \cong C_2 \times C_2$, namely the diagonal one.